# Does unlocking more cards increase odds of getting a card?

Tags: animation-throwdown

In the adventure area, repeated victories against an opponent unlocks additional cards under their "chance pool".  Does this mean that the more cards unlocked, the better the chances of getting a card from a win?

So, for example, if I have 1 card unlocked in, and win, the first stage, I have some chance of getting that card (and I unlock the second card).  Now, if I battle again, am I more likely to get one of the cards than the previous battle.  I suppose another way to put it would be: is the chance of getting a card based on the number of cards in the chance pool?

Answer (score 1):

You can get cards randomly but I don't think that increases the chance of getting a card after you win. Repeated victories unlocks the opponent to silver then gold. When you beat all the people on the islands (gold) then it might start an objective to beat the whole island silver and gold (which takes a while im not finished myself) also back to the top, after repeated victories it unlocks the card to be earned or purchased like for instance, say you buy a card pack for 10k, you could get a card you unlocked. I have a whole bunch of king of the hill cards even though im Leela. And no the chance has little to do with it only for Arena.